# How to disable ctrl-d in kile

Tags: kile

I have found increasingly that I am accidentally typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> instead of ctrl-f only to silently comment out an entire paragraph I am working on.

Is there a way to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> ? Ideally I would still like to be able to comment out paragraphs so if it can be mapped to some other keyboard shortcut that would be even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems too easy to be the correct answer:

However, just click on `Settings` and then `Configure Shortcuts`. There you find the field `Comment`. Just set it to `Custom` and `None`.

Now `ctrl`-`d` is disabled.

I just tried it and it works perfectly (kile v2.1.3).

Comment: I really should have found that but thank you! Now I just need to think of something new to map it to.